# CopyAssets with AsyncTaks to sdcard only once Android

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I would like my app to copy files into the sdcard only when it is open the first time, and not every time I open the app.

Can someone please help complete the code so it only copies the assets if they are not already there?

The portion of my code that copy the assets is under:
**private class Asyntasking extends AsyncTask**

Here is my code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

 private ProgressBar progressBar;
 private int progressStatus = 0;
 private TextView textView;
 private Handler handler = new Handler();
public static final String TAG = "SplashScreen";
    String now_playing, earned;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Asyntasking().execute();

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    // Start long running operation in a background thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          while (progressStatus < 100) {
             progressStatus += 1;

      handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
         textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
      }
          });
          try {
           Thread.sleep(350);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
    }).start();
   }   

private class Asyntasking extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    private void copyAssets(String path)
    {
        String[] files = null;

        try
        {
            files = getAssets().list(path);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (files.length == 0)
            copyFile(path);
        else
        {
            File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);

            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                copyAssets(path + "/" + files[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(String filename)
    {
        InputStream in = null;

        File file;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try
        {
            in = getAssets().open(filename);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH in = getAssets().open: " + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

        try
        {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH out = new FileOutputStream(file);");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] data;

        try
        {
            data = new byte[in.available()];

            in.read(data);
            out.write(data);

            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }}
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        copyAssets("ErgonomicsHelp");
                return null;
    }


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("now_playing", now_playing);
    i.putExtra("earned", earned);
    startActivity(i);

    // close this activity
    finish();
}}
}
```

it works fine, I just want to make it happen once but not sure how to change it.
Thank you,
Derek

Comment: You should save the state in SharedPreferences.

Comment: There are a lot of things that can destroy copying threads. Hence,include a file lists with checksums of files in your assets as well. This way you can remove incomplete files, and resume copying properly on next start.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your AsyncTask to run once. You'll have to save the state somewhere, but the easiest is in a SharedPreference. You would do something like:

```
    private static final String ASYNC_TASK_HAS_RUN = "asynctask_has_run";

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs.getBoolean(ASYNC_TASK_HAS_RUN, false)){
        new Asyntasking().execute();
        prefs.setBoolean(ASYNC_TASK_HAS_RUN, true);
    }
```

Also, I noticed that you're creating a thread to publish the results to a progress. AsyncTasks already have an onProgress method that runs on the main thread, so you can leverage that.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to check if the file already exists on the filesystem (use File.exists), and not copy if it does.  An even fancier way would be to check the timestamp of the file, so if you update the app you can copy over newer data files.